# Create a file download link to a dynamically generated file in Google Colab jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter, google-colaboratory, file-link

How do you get FileLink(filename) to work in Google Colab in order to generate a download link? Is there a better way than FileLink?

Right now this code generates a download link pointing to localhost:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import FileLink, FileLinks

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
df.to_csv('mydf.csv', index=False)
FileLink('mydf.csv')
```

The link generated as output points to: https://localhost:8080/myfile.csv

How do I get it to point to the correct file?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('mydf.csv')
```

Or, more simply, use the file browser in the left hand pane.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't fully answer the question (how to generate dynamic file links in colabra), but it solves my problem! :-)